# knitr + lyx: an error in practice of exact logistic regression

Tags: r, knitr, lyx, verbatim

As you may know, there is a technique, called exact logistic regression. The idre from UCLA provides excellent analysis example. (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/exlogit.htm)
When I exercise with the example analysis, I face an error for knitr (+ lyx).

In the middle of a list of syntax in the Webpage, the syntax below produces an error. Knitr seems to interpret the chunk well, but lyx produces an error related to pdf output.

```
<<>>=
## model with female predictor only'
m.female <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ female, interest = ~female, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)
@
```

lyx produces an error message like this:

```
Running: pdflatex  "logistics.regression.tex" > /dev/null
11:50:28.071: Error while exporting format: pdf2../../../src/support/Systemcall.cpp(270): Systemcall: 'pdflatex  "logistics.regression.tex"' finished with exit code 1
```

Meanwhile, In the error box of lyx, I see the message below:

```
\end{verbatim}                    
You need to provide a definition with \DeclareInputText or \DeclareInputMath before using this key
```

The syntax above in the chunk, however, works well in R terminal without any problem. Should I add an knitr option for the chunk? Then, what is it? Thank you in advance.

Jong-Hwa

```
require(knitr)
require(elrm)
dat <- read.table(text = " 
female  apcalc    admit       num
 0        0        0         7
 0        0        1         1
 0        1        0         3 
 0        1        1         7
 1        0        0         5
 1        0        1         1
 1        1        0         0
 1        1        1         6",
   header = TRUE)
dat
summary(dat)
dat <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$num), -4]
summary(dat)
xtabs(~ female + apcalc, data=dat)
xtabs(~ female + admit, data=dat)
xtabs(~ apcalc + admit, data=dat)
xtabs(~ female + apcalc + admit, data=dat)
x <- xtabs(~admit + interaction(female, apcalc), data = dat) 
x  # view cross tabs
cdat <- data.frame(female = rep(1:0, 2), apcalc = rep(1:0, each = 2), admit = x[1, ], ntrials = colSums(x)) 
cdat  # view collapsed data set
## model with female predictor only
m.female <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ female, interest = ~female, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)
####### the last syntax causes an error in lyx (+ knitr)
```

Comment: 1. Please post a minimal example if possible; 2. Also post the output of `library(knitr); sessionInfo()`.

Comment: from Jong-Hwa:R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=ko_KR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=ko_KR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ko_KR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=ko_KR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=ko_KR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=ko_KR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

Answer (score 2):

The problem came from the progress bar (specifically the backspace `\b`). Two possible solutions:

1. Contact the author of `elrm` and request an argument `progress = TRUE/FALSE` in `elrm()` so that you can suppress the progress bar with, e.g., `elrm(..., progress = FALSE)`;
2. Move the call to `elrm()` to a separate chunk and hide the output of the progress bar, e.g.,

   ```
   <<>>=
   require(elrm)
   dat <- read.table(text = "
   female  apcalc    admit       num
    0        0        0         7
    0        0        1         1
    0        1        0         3 
    0        1        1         7
    1        0        0         5
    1        0        1         1
    1        1        0         0
    1        1        1         6",
      header = TRUE)
   dat
   summary(dat)
   dat <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$num), -4]
   summary(dat)
   xtabs(~ female + apcalc, data=dat)
   xtabs(~ female + admit, data=dat)
   xtabs(~ apcalc + admit, data=dat)
   xtabs(~ female + apcalc + admit, data=dat)
   x <- xtabs(~admit + interaction(female, apcalc), data = dat) 
   x  # view cross tabs
   cdat <- data.frame(female = rep(1:0, 2), apcalc = rep(1:0, each = 2), admit = x[1, ], ntrials = colSums(x)) 
   cdat  # view collapsed data set
   ## model with female predictor only
   @

   <<results='hide'>>=
   m.female <- elrm(formula = admit/ntrials ~ female, interest = ~female, iter = 22000, dataset = cdat, burnIn = 2000)
   @

   <<>>=
   summary(m.female)
   @
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. The 'results='hide'' option and separating summary() from it is very useful, when I meet some functions with progress bar. Thank you indeed.